# How to pass variable and return data to another javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm trying to seprate my `main()` function to 3 diferent js file. Here the file that i want to create :

`query.js` that contain variable, query & fetch function
`viewdata.js` contain DOM component that created using data from fetch
`main.js` that contain function to call fetch and DOM Element

also here my roughly working main() in main.js

```
function main(keyword) {

let season = keyword;
let date = new Date();
let localyear = date.getFullYear();
var query;

let query = `
query ($page: Int, $perPage: Int, $seasonYear: Int, $search: String) {
  ...
}
`;

if(season == "Spring"){
  ... //pick static query that match keyword
}

let variables = {
  ... //variable to assign to query
};


let url = 'myurl',
    options = { ...
    };

fetch(url, options).then(handleResponse)
                   .then(handleData)
                   .catch(handleError);
}
//end of query.js that i want

//start of viewdata.js that i want
function handleResponse(response) {
    return response.json();
}

function handleData(data) {
    const listDataElement = document.querySelector("data-list");


    data.data.Page.media.forEach(media => {
            ... //this DOM Element created from data.data.Page.media array
        });

}

function handleError(error) {
    alert('Error, check console');
    console.error(error);
}

export default main;
```

`main()` function is called using `main(keyword)` where `keyword` is used to pick static query that i created.

I was trying using `return results` function before, but it not work as i want (the data result is not sent to main.js from `fetch .then` in query.js), did anyone can help me with this kind of things? thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the definition of `handleData`? Btw, what is the order in which you load your script snippets? Have you checked the console whether it reports errors (eg. Uncaught reference)?

Comment: `.then(handleData)` is used to call `function handleData(data)` that i use to get data return from API and show it using DOM Element, if i write the data flow it will be like this:

 `main.js` send keyword to `query.js` >> `query.js` fetch query and return **data** from API >> send it to `datalist.js` to render it on HTML.
no error neither result is showed when i try using `return results` to make 3 js, but if i just write everything in 1 file, is worked fine.

Comment: Scripts are not isolated from each other after loading. Change the order by which you include the scripts. What you reference in any file should have been included before ( unfortunately I still do not understand completely how you have organized the code, so the following order is just a guess: datalist.js, query.js, viewdata.js, main.js ).

Comment: here my repl.it https://repl.it/@Darkerside/Export-Data. error said `Cannot access 'renderResult' before initialization` on `main.js` and idk if this approach will work as i want. what function i should change?

Comment: Ok, in `main.js` there is the call `DataSource.searchMovie(keyword).then(renderResult)` but `renderResult` is never declared - what do you expect it to be ?

Comment: i want `renderResult` to call `searchMovie(keyword)` in `query.js` then pass the API result given by fetch there to `viewdata.js`, so the `viewdata.js` can render data array onto html. which one i should change/rewrite?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the declarations of  `renderResult` and `fallbackResult` in `main.js`. However they come after the call site - move them before `DataSource.searchMovie(keyword).then(renderResult)`. You do not define the actual parameter `keyword` in this call, btw.

Comment: here my improved https://repl.it/@Darkerside/Export-Data-1, let say the keyword is 'Spring'. but i face another error `dataresult is not defined` at `viewdata.js` i think the `data[ ]` array from `query.js` is not passed to `viewdata.js`. thanks in advance you helped me a lot